# CFLDAP name attribute...can't use struct?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

This is in CF11/2016.  When I try to use a struct variable (i.e., local.o) for the "name" attribute in a CFLDAP query, it throws an error:

```
Attribute validation error for tag CFLDAP.

The value of the attribute name, which is currently local.o, is invalid.
```

local["o"] doesn't work, either.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you attempting to run the tag inside a function and have keep the result local to the function?

Comment: I'm used to using the local scope inside a CFC...it's been my default way of coding for a while now.  So this is what it looks like:
<cfcomponent>...<cffunction...
<cfset local = StructNew()>
<cfldap action="query" 
 server="#arguments.ADServer#" 
 name="local.ManagerSelect"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this another way.

```
<cffunction>
<cfset var ManagerSelect = ''>  <!--- keeps the variable local to the function --->
<cfldap action = "query" name = "ManagerSelect">
<cfset local.OtherVariable = "something else">
etc
</cffunction>
```

Note that the line `<cfset local = StructNew()>` is unnecessary inside a function.

Comment: Thanks, Dan.  I've been using local for so long that I forgot about the var!  Good to know that the local StructNew() is redundant, too. :)

Comment: FWIW, that issue is listed in the bug database as "Won'tFix". https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4199831